# Как вы описываете интерфейсы во ViewHolder RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin, интерфейс

Я немного почистил код. Мой класс **`BookmarkFragment`** имеет вложенный класс `MyViewHolder` в котором я описал интерфейс, он мне нужен для того чтобы при клике вызвал следующий фрагмент. В методе `onAttach` я его инициализировал.

А как бы вы решили данную задачу? Еще если вы знаете как улучшить читабельность кода, покажите.

```
class BookmarkFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var recycler : RecyclerView

    companion object {
        var lists : ArrayList<Bookmark> = ArrayList()
        private var listener: MyViewHolder.OnItemSelectedListener? = null
        lateinit var bD_bookmark : BD_bookmark
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is MyViewHolder.OnItemSelectedListener) {
            listener = context as MyViewHolder.OnItemSelectedListener?
        } else {
            throw ClassCastException(context!!.toString() + " must implement MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener")
        }
    }


    fun startBookmark(list : ArrayList<Bookmark>){
        //**2**. После тогда как пункт 1 (см. ниже) выполняется, данные придут в этот метод 

        lists = list
        recycler.adapter = MyAdapter()
    }

    @Nullable
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, @Nullable container: ViewGroup?, @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false)

        bD_bookmark = BD_bookmark(providesToDoDao(providesAppDatabase(this.context!!)))
        bD_bookmark.loadTasks(this) // **1**. Прошу Room предоставить массив данных.

        recycler = root.findViewById(R.id.recycler) as RecyclerView
        return root
    }


    class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {


        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false)
            return MyViewHolder(itemView, this@MyAdapter)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val d : ColorDrawable = ColorDrawable(Color.argb(0xff, 0, 0, position * 5))

            ViewCompat.setBackground(holder.image, d)
            holder.text.text = lists[position].title
        }


        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return lists.size
        }


    }

    class MyViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View, val adapter: MyAdapter) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        interface OnItemSelectedListener {
            fun onRssItemSelected(bookmark: Bookmark)
        }

        internal val image: View
        internal val text: TextView
        internal val delete : ImageView

        init {

            this.image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image)
            this.text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)
            this.delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_botton)


            delete.setOnClickListener({it ->
                Log.d("REMOVE ITEM", "YES")
                remove() //удаляем выбранную закладку.
            })
            text.setOnClickListener({
                // 3. Если нажать на текст, должен вызваться фрагмент.
                // я читал, что фрагмент лучше вызвать активити, поэтому
                // я описал интерфейс выше.   
                listener!!.onRssItemSelected(lists[0]);
            })

        }

    }

}
```

**Дополнил**

```
class BookmarkActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BookmarkFragment.MyViewHolder.OnItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.bookmark_activity)

        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_bookmark, BookmarkFragment())
                .commit()
    }

//4 Как только было нажатие по тексу, я вызываю этот метод, который запускает fragment.
    fun fragment2(){
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.preview, PreviewBookmarkFragment())
                .commit()
    }

    override fun onRssItemSelected(bookmark: Bookmark) {
        Log.d("FRAGMENT CALL", " Был вызван")
        fragment2()
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста мой вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845031/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-getfragmentmanager/845033#845033 Я приводил его в другом вопросе, но писать второй раз - лень)

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев спасибо, вы ответили на мой вопрос, даже больше.

Answer (score 1):

Мои субьективные советы.

1. избавьтесь от `companion object`
2. `MyAdapter` может обойтись без передачи ссылки на внешний класс, если я что-то упустил, то переименуйте параметр конструктора. `Fragment` не может называться `activity`.
3. Интерфейс `OnItemSelectedListener` не нужен. Передавайте лямбду в `startBookmark` и далее в `MyAdapter`. Это же `Kotlin`.

Пример кода:

```
fun startBookmark(list : ArrayList<Bookmark>, onItemSelected: (bookmark: Bookmark) -> Unit){
    lists = list
    recycler.adapter = MyAdapter(onItemSelected)
}
```

Далее в `ViewHolder`:

```
text.setOnClickListener({
    adapter.onItemSelected(lists[0]);
})
```

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за ответ, но вы наверное не правильно меня поняли. Дело в том, что код перед публикацией я почистил и он стал непонятным. Я обновил вопрос последов вашими рекомендациями и в комментариях указал пошаговую логику моей программы.

Comment: Если я всё это скопирую и вставлю, код не компилируется. Я хочу уточнить, т.к не работал с лямбдами в таком формате. MyAdapter должен иметь такой конструктор  `MyAdapter(onItemSelected: (bookmark: Bookmark) -> Unit)` ? Это мне сгенерировала Android Studio. А в коде ` text.setOnClickListener({ adapter.onItemSelected(lists[0]); })` adapter не видит `onItemSelected` пишет ошибку `Unresolved reference: onItemSelected`

Comment: Лямбда тоже может быть полем класса, конструктор: `MyAdapter(val onItemSelected: (bookmark: Bookmark) -> Unit)`